# Xcode: Build fails after pod installation (error: Linker command failed with exit Code 1)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, frameworks, cocoapods

please, can you help me with this ios problem? I use Xcode and swift. I deleted all Derived Data many times. I tryed all solutions for this error from Google. Also uninstall Xcode 10.1 and install 10.0. Same error, not possible to Run after ´pod install´ firebrase, before ´pod install´ Project worked correct. 
Steps: 
1.Built new project 
2.open Firebrase web 
3.new Project 
4.for iOS 
5.copy Bundle Identifier 
6.paste to Firebrase web 
7.download GoogleService.plist 
8.put this file to program 
9.start “pod init” 
10.open Podfile 
11.fill pod ´Firebrase/Analytics´ to Podfile 
12.pod install 
13.open .xcworkspce file 
14.run 
15. build Failed 
16.ERROR

Up to step nr. 11 Project worked correctly (also RUN)
By step 12. When I Run Project, displayed ERROR
[image: error]

Thank you very much and stay health.

Comment: Can you share what your podfile looks like? What happens when you install it?

Answer (score 0):

Even though FirebaseAnyalytics dwells like a separate pod, the main branch states you must use Xcode 10.3 or later https://cocoapods.org/pods/Firebase

Answer (score 0):

1. Open your podfile and comment out every single pod.
2. Run pod install so you now have zero dependencies.
3. Uncomment every pod.
4. Run pod install so you have all pods installed.
5. Build again.